# Would Java Virtual Machine run on WinRT?

Tags: java, jvm, windows-runtime

It seems to be a simple question, but I wasn't able to find a meaningful answer, only a lot of speculations.

Also, if an answer is yes, which JVM would it be, Oracle's or again something patched by Microsoft?

Specifically: I have a Java desktop application, running on JRE 7, would it run on WinRT?
I mean, can I install JRE 7 on WinRT? Would it run without problems?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes and no.

It would certainly be possible to implement a Java Virtual Machine, or at least a substantial portion of one, using the Windows Runtime APIs and the portions of the Windows API that are usable from a Windows Store app.  However, such a JVM would need to be an interpreting JVM, not a JIT compiling JVM.  JIT compilation requires the ability to change memory protection (to allow execution of generated code), but the APIs to change memory protection (`VirtualProtect` and friends) are not callable from user code in a Windows Store app.

So, could you implement an interpreting JVM usable in a Windows Store app?  Probably.  Whether or not it would be possible to implement a JVM that performs well enough to be usable is another matter altogether, though.

Comment: Thanks for a detailed explanation. What about browser plugins, applets, JNLP then?

Comment: I know almost nothing about Java, sorry.  But, if it is possible, and if a JRE is required, then it would have to follow the Windows Store app rules, so you'd be in the same boat.

Comment: This is a really old answer, but still is the first response on Google.  I think much has changed since 2012 and it would be good to revisit this topic today.